# Wacom tablet causing crashing/freezing on Mutter X11

Tags: xorg, wacom, mutter

I have been having consistent issues with Wacom tablets on Ubuntu 23.10. On some applications such as Krita, whenever the pen touches the tablet, the window will immediately freeze and become unresponsive until you tab out and tab back in.

Krita and Gimp are the only two applications that would freeze, and using the pen to interact with normal UI elements in any other application had no issues. I suspect the correlation is that they both care about pen pressure. I also tried using Krita's official appimage, which made no difference.

It only happens when using X11 (which I'm current stuck on because of how XWayland doesn't play nice with my laptop's hardware). This issue doesn't happen even when running Krita through XWayland, even though Krita only officially supports X11.

I did some digging, and found that I could remove the stock Wacom driver `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` and just use libinput. This fixed the freezing, but now whenever you click on the top bar with the pen, Ubuntu freezes and then crashes. For the record, I don't know all *that* much about how drivers on Linux work.

I was able to replicate this on a completely fresh Ubuntu install on two separate machines, the only significant similarity being that they both have Nvidia graphics and are using the same tablet (a Wacom CTL-672). Notably, the current release version of Fedora Workstation also experiences this issue. Kubuntu, however, even when running in X11, does not.

Some of the issues closed by [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/3393) bugfix seem to be precisely what my issue is. Sure enough, on Arch linux, my Wacom tablet works perfectly, both when using input-wacom and libinput. That, combined with the fact that it works fine on Kubuntu, tells me that this is just a bug with the version of Mutter that Ubuntu 23.10 ships with.

If this is the case, does anyone know if this bugfix will end up in the next Ubuntu update? And, until then, is there any kind of workaround?

Comment: I have several wacom tablets in 23.04, with X11, no issues. Im wondering if its a support library gimp & krita expect, not provided by mutter. do those softwares depend on gdk?

Comment: @j0h I'll try 23.04 and see if that works. If you dont mind me asking, what kernel version are you running? And what models of Wacom tablets?

Comment: I have an intuos, intous pro, and bamboo wacom tablets. 6.2.0-39-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:18:00 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu Mate, using X11

Comment: @j0h So I can confirm that this is an issue specific to the stock GNOME version of Ubuntu 23.10. Ubuntu 23.04 works, and any flavors of Ubuntu that use a different window manager (Kubuntu, and presumably Ubuntu Mate) also work, even on 23.10.